# Why do we see two dots in the Stern-Gerlach experiment? The "spin measurement" argument does not make sense to me

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Ok, I suppose everyone here is familiar with what the SG experiment is. After recalling the basic idea yesterday I was left with the sensation that I don't understand what is going on.

So, a beam of neutral atoms approaches the region of an inhomogeneous magnetic field, and because these atoms have [spin] angular momentum, they are getting deflected by the field. And then these atoms get detected when they hit the screen. Now, the common explanation says that because the spin of an atom is quantized, we see only a set of discrete dots on the screen as opposed to a continuous line: by making the atoms go through the magnetic field we measure their spin, and the measurement acquires a set of discrete values.

But here's what I'm struggling with: what we really *measure* in the SG experiment is the particle's coordinate $z$ when it hits the screen, but not its angular momentum! While the particle is passing through the inhomogeneous magnetic field its quantum state $|\psi\rangle$ undergoes a unitary evolution according to the Hamiltonian of the "particle + magnetic field" system. There is no measurement here! Assuming atoms with all possible initial quantum states are incoherently emitted by the source towards the magnetic field, we should expect the average value of the spin angular momentum $\langle \psi | \hat s | \psi \rangle$ to exhibit a continuous spectrum after passing through the magnetic field. Similarly, their vertical coordinate. But the way I understand this experiment, the very act of measurement is done only when the particle finally hits the screen, and at that point only we can say "Aha! this particle has spin up/down"

...

Wow, looks like by writing this down I figured out why I struggled with this. The particles' coordinates will evolve along with their spins under the same $\hat H$. This evolution will be represented by a discrete superposition of paths. So yes, although we do in the end measure the particle's coordinate only, the particle can end up only on one of the few discrete points, belonging to the path allowed by the unitary evolution operator. Wow.

Thanks stackexchange!

Comment: Hello and welcome. The preference here would be for you to write an answer to your own question (just move the last part of your question into an answer). Then you can accept your answer if you wish.